# I have a code error in android studio .java

Tags: android-studio

```
package com.code.files.utils;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.media3.cast.CastPlayer;
import androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton;



import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastButtonFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext;

public class ChromeCastUtil implements CastPlayer.**SessionAvailabilityListener** {

    private CastContext castContext;
    private static CastPlayer castPlayer;


    public void initCast(MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton, Context context) {
        CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(context.getApplicationContext(), mediaRouteButton);
        castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(context);
        castPlayer = new CastPlayer(castContext);
        castPlayer.setSessionAvailabilityListener(this);

    }


    public void onCastSessionAvailable() {

    }


    public void onCastSessionUnavailable() {

    }
}
```

```
error: cannot access BasePlayer
public class ChromeCastUtil implements CastPlayer.SessionAvailabilityListener {
                                                 ^
  class file for androidx.media3.common.BasePlayer not found
```